# how to hide drawer in react router flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

hey there i am working with react native project and i am using react router flux for navigation and i use Drawer so how can i disable the drawer in some screens ? like signin screen ?

i tried  drawerLockMode={'lock-closed'} but it's not working

here is mycode

```
 <RouterRedux backAndroidHandler={() => {}}>
      <Drawer>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar transitionConfig={transitionConfig}>
          <Scene key="Tuto" component={Tuto} type={ActionConst.RESET} />
          <Scene
            initial
            key="CheckAuth"
            component={CheckAuth}
            type={ActionConst.RESET}
          />
          <Scene key="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Scene key="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Scene key="Visits" component={Visits} />
          <Scene key="VisitDetails" component={VisitDetails} />
          <Scene key="Statistiques" component={Statistiques} />
        </Scene>
      </Drawer>
    </RouterRedux>
```

Comment: did you try passing `drawerLockMode` to each individual scene?

Comment: yes i tried but it didnt work

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far and put it in the above code? and i meant passing `lock-closed` for disabled scenes and `unlocked` for enabled scenes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the drawerLockMode in the principal scene.. something like that

```
<RouterRedux backAndroidHandler={() => {}}>
  <Drawer>
    <Scene 
       key="root" 
       hideNavBar 
       transitionConfig={transitionConfig}
       drawerLockMode='locked-closed' //New line
     >
      <Scene key="Tuto" component={Tuto} type={ActionConst.RESET} />
      <Scene
        initial
        key="CheckAuth"
        component={CheckAuth}
        type={ActionConst.RESET}
      />
      <Scene key="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
      <Scene key="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
      <Scene key="Visits" component={Visits} />
      <Scene key="VisitDetails" component={VisitDetails} />
      <Scene key="Statistiques" component={Statistiques} />
    </Scene>
  </Drawer>
</RouterRedux>
```

If you want to lock/unlock in different scenes you need to separate with a parent Scene each group of Scenes that you want to lock/unlock the drawer...

```
<RouterRedux backAndroidHandler={() => { }}>
    <Drawer
        hideNavBar
        open={false}
        key="drawer"
        contentComponent={SideBar}
        drawerWidth={300}
    // drawerLockMode={show ? 'locked-closed' : 'unlocked'}>
    >
        <Scene
            key="root" hideNavBar
            transitionConfig={transitionConfig}
            drawerLockMode='locked-closed'
        >
            <Scene key="Tuto" component={Tuto} type={ActionConst.RESET} />
            <Scene
                initial
                key="CheckAuth"
                component={CheckAuth}
                type={ActionConst.RESET}
            />
        </Scene>
        <Scene
            key="root2"
            hideNavBar
            transitionConfig={transitionConfig}
            drawerLockMode='unlocked'
        >
            {/*<Scene key="WIP" component={WorkInProgress} />*/}
            <Scene key="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
            <Scene key="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
            <Scene key="Visits" component={Visits} />
            <Scene key="VisitDetails" component={VisitDetails} />
            <Scene key="Statistiques" component={Statistiques} />
            <Scene key="Notification" component={Notification} />
            <Scene key="Sync" component={Sync} />
        </Scene>
    </Drawer>
</RouterRedux>
```

I hope I've helped ... :)